# create subelement with namespace in xml

Tags: python, xml, soap, namespaces

I want to create this xml, but I don't know how to create the subelement `IsAddSegments` with the namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ISAddSegments xmlns="http://www.blue-order.com/ma/integrationservicews/api">
            <accessKey>key</accessKey>
            <objectID>
                <guid>guid</guid>
            </objectID>
            <StratumName>STRATUM</StratumName>
            <Segments>
                <Segment>
                    <Begin>00:00:00:00</Begin>
                    <Content>TEXT</Content>
                    <End>00:00:10:00</End>
                </Segment>
            </Segments>
        </ISAddSegments>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is what I have:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

Envelope = ET.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope")
Body = ET.SubElement(Envelope, '{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Body')
ET.register_namespace('soapenv', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope')
ISAddSegments = ET.SubElement(Body, '{http://www.blue-order.com/ma/integrationservicews/api}ISAddSegments')
...
```

But this creates an extra namespace in the main element and that's not what I need.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.blue-order.com/ma/integrationservicews/api" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:ISAddSegments>
```

Comment: Namespace definition should be at the top of xml document so according to that lxml is generating the correct XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree as etree

ns1 = 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'
ns2 = 'http://www.blue-order.com/ma/integrationservicews/api'

Envelope = etree.Element('{ns1}Envelope', nsmap = {'soapenv': ns1})
Body = etree.SubElement(Envelope, '{ns1}Body')
ISAddSegments = etree.SubElement(Body, 'ISAddSegments', nsmap = {None : ns2})
accessKey = etree.SubElement(ISAddSegments, 'accessKey')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a dedicated SOAP module such as `suds`. Then you can create a custom namespace by providing `ns` to `Element`. The value should be a tuple containing the namespace name and a url in which it's defined:

```
from suds.sax.element import Element

custom_namespace = ('custom_namespace', 'http://url/namespace.xsd')
element_with_custom_namespace = Element('Element', ns=custom_namespace)

print(element_with_custom_namespace)
# <custom_namespace:Element xmlns:custom_namespace="http://url/namespace.xsd"/>
```

Comment: How do I generate the rest of the xml? I don't find a lot of information to do this with `suds`